# Point-n-Click JQuery selector Generator?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Are there any plugins or other tools that would allow me to point to an element on a web page and get back a jquery (or css) selector query?

I'm looking for something to be used by very non-technical people to use where they could "highlight" a page item and then get the appropriate jquery statement to "navigate" properly to that element - anything out there that exists for this?

Comment: That's not a very concrete question. There are numerous selectors which can be used to point to a certain element - IDs, classes, attributes, ...

Comment: William, please explain what you want to achieve in a bit more detail. I didn't quite get what you want it to do.

Answer (score 4):

Both Firefox's Firebug and Chrome's inspect tool have this feature.  Just right click->inspect, and it lists out a CSS selector structure.

Answer (score 1):

Is this something like what you are looking for?

**Updated, its probably not the nicest solution but I'm hungry ^__^ :**

```
var root = document.body;
var listen = function(element, evt, func){
    if(element.addEventListener)
        element.addEventListener(evt, func, false);
    else if(element.attachEvent)
        element.attachEvent('on'+evt, func);
};

var buildchain = function(element, chain){
    if(element == document.body){
        return true;
    }
    else if(element.id != ""){
        chain.push("#" + element.id);
        return true;
    }
    else if(element.className != "")
        chain.push("." + element.className);
    else
        chain.push("" + element.tagName);
    buildchain(element.parentNode, chain);
}

var buildstring = function(){
    var str = "$('" + chain[chain.length-1] + "')";
    for(var i = chain.length-2; i >= 0; i--){
        str += (".children('" + chain[i] + "')");
    }
    return str;
}
listen(root, 'click', function(evt){
    chain = [];
    buildchain(evt.target, chain);
    var s = buildstring();
    alert(s);
});
```

Comment: It's a start, but for instance if the target has a class-name then you should recursively look up the DOM tree to find something more unique so the selector would be something like `$('#something-with-an-id').children('div').children('.' + evt.target.className)`.

Comment: Good point @Jasper, I'm about to make dinner but I might write a more thorough solution once I get back (although feel free to do so yourself if you feel like it) :)

Comment: I seem not to have read through the question thoroughly enough as op is asking for a tool/plugin. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

http://selectorgadget.com

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selectorgadget/mhjhnkcfbdhnjickkkdbjoemdmbfginb

> SelectorGadget is an open source tool that makes CSS selector
>   generation and discovery on complicated sites a breeze. Just install
>   the Chrome  Extension or drag the bookmarklet to your bookmark bar,
>   then go to any page and launch it. A box will open in the bottom right
>   of the website. Click on a page element that you would like your
>   selector to match (it will turn green). SelectorGadget will then
>   generate a minimal CSS selector for that element, and will highlight
>   (yellow) everything that is matched by the selector. Now click on a
>   highlighted element to remove it from the selector (red), or click on
>   an unhighlighted element to add it to the selector. Through this
>   process of selection and rejection, SelectorGadget helps you come up
>   with the perfect CSS selector for your needs.
>
> **How could I use this?**
>
> 1. for webpage scraping with tools such as Nokogiri and Beautiful Soup
> 2. to generate jQuery selectors for dynamic sites
> 3. as a tool to examine JavaScript-generated DOM structures
> 4. as a tool to help you style only particular elements on the page with
>      your stylesheets
> 5. for selenium or phantomjs testing
>
> **Created by Andrew Cantino and Kyle Maxwell. You can find the current
>   version on GitHub, and please feel free to leave comments below.**

Answer (score 0):

i make some modifications incase you don't want to use jquery and need the selector to work with document.querySelector()

```
const root = document.body;
const listen = function(element, evt, func){
    if(element.addEventListener)
        element.addEventListener(evt, func, false);
    else if(element.attachEvent)
        element.attachEvent('on'+evt, func);
};

const buildchain = function(element, chain){
    if(element == document.body){
        return true;
    }
    else if(element.id != ""){
        chain.push("#" + element.id);
        return true;
    }
    else if(element.className != ""){
        let strclass = ""
        element.className.split(" ").map((value) => {
            if (value) {
                strclass += "." + value
            }
        })
        chain.push(strclass);
    }
    else {
        chain.push("" + element.tagName);
    }
    buildchain(element.parentNode, chain);
}

var buildstring = function(){
    let str
    if (chain[chain.length-1]) {
        str = chain[chain.length-1];
    }
    for(let i = chain.length-2; i >= 0; i--){
        if (chain[i]) {
            str += (" " + chain[i]);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
listen(root, 'click', function(evt){
    chain = [];
    buildchain(evt.target, chain);
    var s = buildstring();
    alert(s);
});
```